# NSArray key => value,

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

My key value current system isn't working. Here where the array is set.

```
NSArray *matchInfo = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                          @{@"matchName" : _matchName},
                          @{@"hostName" : _hostName},
                          nil];
```

Then is it converted into `NSData`

```
NSData *dataToSend = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:message];
```

Received and set

```
    NSArray *receivedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:receivedData];

    _matchName = [receivedArray valueForKey:@"matchName"];
    _hostName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[receivedArray valueForKey:@"hostName"]];

    NSLog(@"%@, %@", _matchName, _hostName);
```

The reason they're different is because I was toying with different ways. However, the nslog provides this.

(
    HostMatch,
    ""
), (
    "",
    HostName
)

Which I cannot understand, only makes me thing that the array is initially setup wrong.

Comment: log `matchInfo` and `receivedArray`, that is just basic debugging. Debugging is a major part of developing software.

Comment: Looks perfectly normal to me, given the (screwy) input. Why have an array with dictionaries where each dictionary contains only one key/value pair?

Comment: (And it's dangerous to use `valueForKey` when you don't understand what you're doing, since it merely confuses you more.)

Comment: @HotLicks The data is sent via bluetooth, so I don't necissarily want a dictionary for each key. I'd rather have like the old days

array(
"key" => "value",
"key" => "value); so I can reference valueAtKey "key" example..?

Comment: A single dictionary will associate keys with values.

Comment: Is this considered a bad question by the way? as I did try searching for NSArray key => value examples and couldn't find any. Or at least enough to end up with what I ended up with. In other languages I've used Arrays for this sort of thing. Could anyone tell me why a question like this get's downvoted? I don't want to end up disabled from asking questions and would like a few pointers on how to ask a better question, from this example.

Comment: It is a bad question because you really should have an understanding of what an NSDictionary is right from the start, when working with Objective-C.  You should not be asking for help with such fundamental concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should have is:

```
NSDictionary *matchInfo = @{@"matchName" : _matchName,
                            @"hostName"  : _hostName};
```

Comment: I don't necessarily want a dictionary, is it possible to do this on a key => value basis?

Comment: @Daniel - That's exactly what a dictionary does -- it associates each key with a value.

Comment: Why would someone down vote this answer? It could use some explanation as to why this code should be used but it is the right answer.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm not sure, perhaps someone got a bit butthurt by one of their comments on an answer.

Comment: @rmaddy Since it's just a copy paste of my answer

Comment: Kind of like repeating other's answers ;)

Comment: @Rick - So you're saying your answer was "correct" as originally written -- that you didn't edit it?  (At my prodding)

Comment: Of course I edited it, but instead of simply waiting the roughly 30 seconds for my edit you went on and posted the correction (Which consisted of removing two characters) as your own answer? Stay classy!

Comment: @Rick - I did not copy your answer.  I keyed that in "fresh".  I would have had it done 3-4 minutes sooner, but I was busy explaining why the other answers were wrong.  Sorry you got your shorts in such a knot, but that's the way it works.

Comment: You do know there is an edit-button which is available to you, considering the amount of rep you have?

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSArray *array = @[@{@"key1" : @"value1"}, //-index 0-//
                       @{@"key2" : @"value2"}, //-index 1-//
                       @{@"key3" : @"value3"}, //-index 2-//
                       @{@"key4" : @"value4"}]; //-index 3-//

    int i = 0; //-index 0 - 3-//
    NSDictionary *dict = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    NSArray *key = [dict allKeys];
    NSArray *value = [dict allValues];
    NSLog(@"%@", key[0]);
    NSLog(@"%@", value[0]);

result :

2015-08-04 11:46:20.781 key1
2015-08-04 11:46:20.781 value1
```

Answer (score 0):

`@{@"matchName" : _matchName}` this is shorthand for `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:_matchname, @"matchName"]`. What this means is that you have an `NSArray` with two `NSDictionaries`.

What you probably want is a single NSDictionary with the two keys instead. Like so:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"matchName" : _matchName, @"hostName" : _hostName}
```

This corresponds to the array( "key" => "value", "key" => "value) type of array from PHP and other languages.

Comment: @Rick Thank you for your answer, I'd up vote it if my reputation was a little higher. Regardless, thank you.